# Set Vertical and Horizontal alignment in PySide2

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyside, pyside2

The `QSplashScreen.showMessage()`method accepts an alignment flag i.e `Qt.AlignLeft`. What is the syntax for setting both a horizontal and vertical alignment flag? All attempts yields "too many variables" error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Qt::Alignment](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#AlignmentFlag-enum) are [QFlags](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qflags.html) that use bitwise operators `&`, `|` and `^`, in the case you want to combine flags you must use the `|` operator, in the next part I show an example:

```
import random
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(640, 480)
    h_alignments = (QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft, QtCore.Qt.AlignRight, QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter, QtCore.Qt.AlignJustify)
    v_alignments = (QtCore.Qt.AlignTop, QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom, QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter, QtCore.Qt.AlignBaseline)
    pixmap.fill(QtGui.QColor("green"))
    w  = QtWidgets.QSplashScreen(pixmap)

    def on_timeout():
        a = random.choice(h_alignments) | random.choice(v_alignments)
        w.showMessage("Stack Overflow", alignment=a)

    timer = QtCore.QTimer(interval=100, timeout=on_timeout)
    timer.start()
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(10*1000, QtWidgets.QApplication.quit)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 4):

From [the Qt5 docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#AlignmentFlag-enum), alignment flags are bit fields so to combine them you use the `|` operator (e.g., `Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop` for "top left" alignment)